# What is the problem with my chance system?

Tags: java

This is my main class:
What happens here is,
i create a list of strings and then add strings which end with :%percentage% they then get split and "outputted" fine but the score is not right.

```
package me.alexmc;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {
    public static List<String> test = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random random = new Random();
        test.add("1st arg with 10% chance:10");
        test.add("2nd arg with 50% chance:50");
        test.add("3rd arg with 20% chance:20");
        test.add("4th arg with 30% chance:30");
        final MyMethods myObj = new MyMethods();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            myObj.chanceSystem(test, random);
        }
        for(String s : myObj.map.keySet()) {
            String[] splitter = s.split(":");
            System.out.println(splitter[0] + ": " + myObj.map.get(s));
        }
    }
}
```

This is my method class where all the magic happens:
For some reason i can't get the percentages to work, they are not right
like 30% happens more than 50% and thats not normal

```
package me.alexmc;

import java.util.*;

public class MyMethods {
    public HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

    public void chanceSystem(List<String> list, Random chanceRandom) {
        int chance;
        String[] strArray;
        for (String s : list) {
            strArray = s.split(":");
            try {
                chance = Integer.parseInt(strArray[1]);
            } catch (NumberFormatException exception) {
                chance = 0;
                System.err.println("Trovato un errore di formattazione chance nel config.yml");
            }
            if (chanceRandom.nextInt(101) <= chance) {
                if(map.get(s) == null) {
                    map.put(s, 0);
                } else {
                    map.replace(s, map.getOrDefault(s, 0)+1);
                }
                return;
            }
        }
        doChance(list, chanceRandom);
    }

    public void doChance(List<String> list, Random random) {
        Collections.sort(list);
        Collections.reverse(list);
        String s = list.get(random.nextInt(list.size()));

        if(map.get(s) == null) {
            map.put(s, 0);
        } else {
            map.replace(s, map.getOrDefault(s, 0)+1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you be more concrete about which output you expect, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, its not quite clear for me what you are trying to achieve, but I can at least try to explain the results you are seeing:

Your return statement in the chanceSystem method is a problem, as it return immediately after the first time the created random number is below the percentage of one of your strings in the list. This means, there is already a pretty high probability the last element in your list will not get evaluated even if the percentage is high. Now the second problem is, that the list is not immutable and the sorting in the doChance will sort the original list, this will bring up the string with the 30% to the head. In combination with the first problem it has now a higher probability to have the highest number in your map, higher than the string with 50%.

Now if you remove the return statement in your chanceSystem method, you will get the following counts:

```
3rd arg with 20% chance: ~450
1st arg with 10% chance: ~350
2nd arg with 50% chance: ~750
4th arg with 30% chance: ~550
```

Each gets an offset of 250 of the doChance method, as this will increment each string with the same probability and each gets the count of the percentage, 200 for 20%, 100 for 10% and so on.

If you comment the doChance method, you wont get the offset of this method and then you should get the numbers which corresponds to their percentage:

```
3rd arg with 20% chance: ~200
1st arg with 10% chance: ~100
2nd arg with 50% chance: ~500
4th arg with 30% chance: ~300
```